# how to open Genymotion in android

Tags: android, genymotion

when I tried to open genymotion in android studio ,

> Unable to start the virtual device.
>   VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device. To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox.
>
> more information, check the log files.

Please refer to: www.genymotion.com/faq/logs

or that said :

Comment: How did you install Genymotion? Did you install just the  android studio plugin or also install Genymotion along with VirtualBox?

Comment: I opened the website of virtualbox and downloaded it , after that I installed it . After all, I opened genymotion website and downloaded it for personal issue and installed it , and tried to plugin it into android studio from file , sittings , plugins , etc

Comment: Did you "try to start the device from VirtualBox"? What are the Genymotion log files saying?

Comment: @AhmedMoftah Ok. Did you create a virtual device yet?

Comment: I installed Genymotion , after VirtualBox . After that , tried to plugin it in android studio

Comment: I created a virtual device in Genymotion and also tried to run it from VirtualBox but it gives me an error .

Comment: @AhmedMoftah Start genymotion. After that if not ready done.. You might have to sign in. Post signin you should create a virtual device. After this you should be able to start the device using genymotion or android studio.

Comment: Update your questions with more details and error log.

Comment: when I open Genymotion and start the virtual device it  gives that error.

Comment: when I tried to run virtual device from virtualBox it gives me an error said :Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error log,

> :Failed to open/create the internal network
>   'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2'
>   (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND). Failed to attach the network LUN
>   (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND). Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>   Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: IConsole
>   {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Open "**Network Connections**" from control panel, select the "**VirtualBox Host-Only Network**" right click and check if "**VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver**" is enabled from properties.

[image]

If the settings looks alright but the device doesn't starts, Uninstall both of the **VirtualBox** and **Genymotion**, reinstall a new package that contains both of the VirtualBox & Genymotion together in a single package. See here,

PS: Try restarting your PC making installing/uninstalling the VirtualBox.

[image]